# Dynamically merging Fluxes

Tags: project-reactor

I've written an application with the server side applying the Event Sourcing pattern, with all incoming commands processed sequentially with the Reactor. I get those commands from client connexions. Alas, my Netty Pipeline publishes commands with no respect for the Reactive Contract. Reactor Netty could be a part of a solution, because it enforces the Reactive Contract down to the Netty Pipeline.

But with Reactor Netty, each connection in a Flux. Connections are added and removed.

How do I merge dynamically several Flux in one? How to round-robin through incoming Fluxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I understood your questions correctly, if you need an event stream whose events are generated in an async way, you can try to use reactor.core.publisher.TopicProcessor.
With TopicProcessor, we created a stack whose event came from several different sources and we can process it as one reactive stream.

I'm also quite new at reactor-netty, but there are very few resources available on the internet, so I would like to provide my humble opinion for your reference.

Comment: That's correct. Quoting Javadoc: "An implementation of a RingBuffer backed message-passing Processor implementing publish-subscribe with async event loops." And: "A Shared Processor authorizes concurrent onNext calls and is suited for multi-threaded publisher that will fan-in data."
Good finding!